# Java Stack Boolean Output Customization?

Tags: java, stack, boolean

So what I have is this slightly modified version of a code that's here a hundred times over for Java Stack Balancing.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

public static String testContent = "{(a,b)}";

public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.out.println(balancedParentheses(testContent));
}

public static boolean balancedParentheses(String s)
{
    Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{' )
        {
            stack.push(c); 
        }else if(c == ']')
        {
            if(stack.isEmpty()) return false;
            if(stack.pop() != '[') return false;

        }else if(c == ')')
        {
            if(stack.isEmpty()) return false;
            if(stack.pop() != '(') return false;

        }else if(c == '}')
        {
            if(stack.isEmpty()) return false;
            if(stack.pop() != '{') return false;
        }

    }
    return stack.isEmpty(); 
}
}
```

What I'd like to do is customize the output such that it would output something like "balanced" or "imbalanced" instead of true/false. Trying to replace return false; with a System.println containing 'balanced' gives me a whole lot of output lines I didn't want. Been searching around here for about an hour and some change and couldn't quite find the answer I was looking for. Any insight?

Comment: System.out.println(balancedParentheses(testContent) ? "balanced" : imbalanced");

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to mark this as a solution, but it definitely did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @BEASTthisIndustry It's because on Stack Overflow you can't accept a comment, but you can accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

`System.out.println(balancedParentheses(testContent) ? "balanced" : "imbalanced");`

OR if you want a method that returns a String wrap the logic in another method

```
String isBalanced(String expression) {
    return balancedParentheses(expression) ? "balanced" : "imbalanced"
}
```

and in main()

```
System.out.println(isBalanced(testContent));
```

**Also** you could write the code something like this

```
public static boolean balancedParentheses(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{') {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (c == ']' || c == ')' || c == '}') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || !matches(stack.pop(), c))
                return false;
        } 
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}

private static boolean matches(char opening, char closing) {
    return opening == '{' && closing == '}' ||
            opening == '(' && closing == ')' ||
            opening == '[' && closing == ']';
}
```

Comment: I love your concise version of the balancedParentheses() code!

Comment: I would use something like `"[({".contains(c)` and in the matches method `String brackets = opening+""+closing;` then do `brackets.equals("()") || brackets.equals("[]")` and so on...